# Dynamic injection angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

i am using one of the basic concept of angularjs that child controller inherit from parent controller. so i have writen the following code :

```
   var editChannelCtrl = function ($scope, $route, $location, youtube) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.saved = false;
    $scope.errors = [];

if (angular.isDefined($route.current.params.id)) {
        $scope.isOldChannel = true;
        $scope.isNewChannel = false;
    } else {
        $scope.isNewChannel = true;
        $scope.isOldChannel = false;
    }
};
editChannelCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$route', '$location', 'youtube'];

editChannelCtrl.resolve = {
    channel: ['ServiceChannel' , function (ServiceChannel) {
        return ServiceChannel.ChannelLoader();
    }]
};

var oldChannelCtrl = function ($scope, $location, channel) {
    $scope.channel = channel;
};
oldChannelCtrl.$inject = ['$scope' , '$location', 'channel'];
var newChannelCtrl = function ($scope, $location, Channel) {
    $scope.channel = {
        id: null,
        version: 1
    };
};
newChannelCtrl.$inject = ['$scope' , '$location',  'Channel'];
```

and for routes what i do , that i resolve the `channel` that load the channel for the edit form with the following code.

```
            .when('/admin/refactor/channel/edit/:id', {
                controller: editChannelCtrl,
                templateUrl: '/admin/assets/views/channelForm.html',
                resolve: editChannelCtrl.resolve
            })
            .when('/admin/refactor/channel/new', {
                controller: editChannelCtrl,
                templateUrl: '/admin/assets/views/channelForm.html'
            })
```

but i don't know why angularjs don't figure how to inject `channel` to `oldChannelCtrl` ?

Comment: Why you have used `Channel` in newChannelCtrl and `channel` in oldChannelCtrl?

Comment: the difference between, that one i have angularjs $resource that i called Channel, for the other channel it's a service that called Channel.get to get the specific Channel the routes id